# How to ignore does not implement Icontroller error in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller class as below:

```
public partial class GenericViewController : Controller
    {
        public virtual void StoreUrl(string url)
        {
            Session["URL"] = url;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to place a call to this method using jquery ajax as below:

```
    $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    cache:false,
                    url: "http://" + baseUrl + "/GenericView/StoreUrl",
                    data: { url: applicationurl },
                    error: Error
                });
```

Now when I trigger the ajax call I get the following error

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/GenericView/StoreUrl&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I have tried doing the following to resolve this in the register routes, but I still receive the same errors

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("Ignore/");
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{*GenericView}", new { GenView= @"(.*/)?GenericView(/.*)?" });
 routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
 routes.IgnoreRoute("GenericView/{*pathInfo}");
```

An Additional Note: This code is hosted in an apllication called LookupData which hosted as application under an IIS website which mapped with url abc.com, then abc.com hosts a application which does authentication and abc.com/LookupData will hit the application which host the above code. Lookupdata when run alone does not throw this error, however when coming via abc.com the application is unable to resolver the GenericViewController.

I dont understand where is the mistake in my code. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: why is the class partial?

Comment: Does the controller allow POST requests? Maybe try changing the method to 'GET' just to see you get the same error. 

If that does not work either, the problem is in the routing, can you post the routing definition?

Comment: @Tallmaris Both POST and GET have the same issue.
In addtion to the ignore routes i have the following in routing definition:
       routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: Wild guess here, can you just change the parameter name in the method from `url` to `id`, and also in the ajax call? MVC is very picky with parameter names... Alternatively, change the routing definition to have `url` rather than `id` as the optional parameter (if that does not break other controllers of course!)

Comment: @Tallmaris I tried that but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your solutions to resolve this issue actually added a bug:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("GenericView/{*pathInfo}");
```

This causes Mvc to ignore any route to the "GenericViewController" - except, maybe, when you're not using "convention over configuration" - thus not calling any method (like StoreUrl) on it.

Adding

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*GenericView}", new { GenView= @"(.*/)?GenericView(/.*)?" });
```

might have the same result.

Just remove the routes.IgnoreRoute("{*GenericView}"